# Add each array element to the lines of a file in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, file, line, output

If I have an array of strings e.g.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

and I want to output the elements, to a file (e.g. .txt) one per line. So far I have:

```
File.new("test.txt", "w+")
File.open("test.txt", "w+") do |i|
    i.write(a)
end
```

This gives me the array on one line of the test.txt file.
How can I iterate over the array, adding each value to a new line of the file?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Either use [`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) to iterate over your array and call [`IO#puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-puts) to write each element to the file (`puts` adds a record separator, typically a newline character):

```
File.open("test.txt", "w+") do |f|
  a.each { |element| f.puts(element) }
end
```

Or pass the whole array to `puts`:

```
File.open("test.txt", "w+") do |f|
  f.puts(a)
end
```

From the documentation:

> If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line.

Comment: Your first suggestion was what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Just a heads-up for people using a set instead of an array: only the first version works.

Comment: @danielf. that's correct, as mentioned in the documentation, you have to call `puts` with an _array argument_ to get that behavior.

Answer (score 24):

There is a quite simpler solution :

```
IO.write("file_name.txt", your_array.join("\n"))
```

Comment: @Dika Suparlan, welcome to SO. A little explanation is also helpful. Not only does it validate your answer but it gives the OP an indication of what they need to do both with the current issue and potentially in future situations. Im sure I'm not alone in wanting to learn from the SO community rather than just being given solutions. The greatest sense of success is in overcoming a good challenge. ;-)

Comment: This should be the preferred answer.  From the doc -- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/IO.html -- IO.write(name, string [, offset] [, opt]) → integer  --- Opens the file, optionally seeks to the given offset, writes string, then returns the length written. write ensures the file is closed before returning. If offset is not given, the file is truncated. Otherwise, it is not truncated.

Answer (score 9):

As an alternate, you could simply join the array with "\n" so that each element is on a new line, like this:

```
a = %w(a b c d)

File.open('test.txt', 'w') {|f| f.write a.join("\n")}
```

If you don't want to override the values already in the text file so that you're simply adding new information to the bottom, you can do this:

```
a = %w(a b c d)

File.open('test.txt', 'a') {|f| f << "\n#{a.join("\n")}"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) to iterate each element. When writing to the file, make sure you append newline(`\n`), or you will get a file with `abcd` as content:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
File.open('test.txt', 'w') do |f|
  a.each do |ch|
    f.write("#{ch}\n")
  end
end
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, See [`Enumerable` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html). There's no `each`.

Comment: What? All these years I thought that each belongs to Enumerable.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, `Enumerable` is a just mixin. It does not define `each` itself.

Comment: Right, it *depends* on `each`.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple solution:

```
directory = "#{Rails.root}/public/your_directory" #create your_directory before
file_name = "your_file.txt"
path = File.join(directory, file_name)
File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(your_array.join("\n")) }
```